# Azure Ubuntu VM - Execute Custom Script (Permission Denied)

Tags: linux, azure, ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04

I created an Azure ARM template, which is using the Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions in an Ubuntu 18.04 in order to execute a custom script. Once the machine is provisioned, the ubuntu user (non-root) should be able to run the custom script from the following directory /var/lib/waagent/custom-script/download/0 it receives "permission denied". I added the following lines to make sure the ubuntu user owns the file and is able to execute, but without success.

```
sudo chown ubuntu install_metaport.sh
chmod +x install_metaport.sh
sh install_metaport.sh
```

I then, changed my approach and added the following inline commands to my Azure ARM script, which worked fine. But I am trying to avoid having to copy/move the file around, and have this executed from its original directory, which is /var/lib/waagent/custom-script/download/0, but again, I end up with "permission denied" and can't figure it out how to get around this issue

```
cp install_metaport.sh /tmp && chown ubuntu /tmp/install_metaport.sh && chmod +x /tmp/install_metaport.sh && cd /tmp && sh install_metaport.sh
```

Any advise?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your file `install_metaport.sh` can be executed by user Ubuntu. You verified that by putting in another directory.

The fact that the file can be executed from another directory tells that permissions are denied at a lower level. Root folder permission limits child files permission, so most likely you cannot execute in the `/var/lib/waagent/custom-script/download/0` directory. Give the user ubuntu executions rights there, and it'll work like a charm.